# Adding relation to object with preview or something like this

Tags: django

I have `Document` model:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    content = models.TextField()
```

and `DocumentRelation` model:

```
class DocumentRelation(models.Model):
    document_a = models.ForeignKey(Document,related_name='doc_a')
    document_b = models.ForeignKey(Document,related_name='doc_b')
```

I have `single_document` views:

```
def single_document(request,id):
    doc = Document.objects.get(id=id)

    return render_to_response('single_file.html',{'doc':doc},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In `single_file.html` I have:

```
<a href="/add-relation/{{ doc.id }}" class="btn btn-success">Add related document</a>
```

I need create views `def add_relation(request,id):`. What is the best way to add the relationship? I need a preview of the document that to be added as related. How to solve it?

(I ask about the overall design. How to solve it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, why are you not using a ManyToManyField in the document model like this :

```
related_documents = models.ManyToManyField('self')
```

Then you can use a two steps form if you do not want to use javascript (one to select, another to confirm and display the related document).

If you want, you can also use javascript and dynamically load the related document when the user select it.

Comment: and use `document.related_documents.add(another_document)`. [see here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships)